# Sending a public key in pynacl as JSON object

Tags: python, json, sockets, nacl-cryptography

I have a server and client setup where when the client connects, it sends over a JSON object with a username and a public_key.

My current code:

```
private_key = PrivateKey.generate()
public_key = private_key.public_key
payload = json.dumps({"username": username, "public_key": public_key}).encode('hex')
```

But I get:

```
TypeError: <nacl.public.PublicKey object at 0x7fc6ecff18d0> is not JSON serializable
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably a bit late but it's explained [here](https://pynacl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/encoding/)

If you want it as Base64 for example you do

```
from nacl.encoding import Base64Encoder
print(public_key.encode(Base64Encoder).decode())
```